# Vendor rating can't be recreated and shown on the product page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am trying to show the star rating of the vendor review in my single product page from wcfm, but I am unable to find a result thus far I either get a no ratings available yet ! or all the star rating are grey.

I am a beginner in coding and I have searched for the fonctions in my website's files and was able to create this (below code), but It seems that it is not fetching the right info I honestly have no idea where I went wrong.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRIlq.png

```
function get_vendor_rating($vendor_id) {
    $store_rating = 0;

    if (function_exists('WCFMmp') && method_exists(WCFMmp(), 'get_vendor_review_rating')) {
        $store_rating = WCFMmp()->get_vendor_review_rating($vendor_id);
    }

    return $store_rating;
}

function get_vendor_reviews_count($vendor_id, $status = 'approved') {
    global $wpdb;

    $reviews_count = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wcfm_marketplace_reviews WHERE vendor_id = %d AND approved = %d";
    $reviews_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $vendor_id, ($status === 'approved' ? 1 : 0)));

    return $reviews_count;
}

function display_vendor_rating() {
    global $product;

    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    $vendor_id = get_post_field('post_author', $product_id);

    echo '<div style="display: none;">Product ID: ' . $product_id . '</div>';
    echo '<div style="display: none;">Vendor ID: ' . $vendor_id . '</div>';

    $vendor_rating = get_vendor_rating($vendor_id);

    if ($vendor_rating || $vendor_rating === 0) {rating is explicitly 0
        $count = get_vendor_reviews_count($vendor_id);
        $star_rating_html = wp_star_rating(array(
            'rating' => $vendor_rating,
            'type'   => 'rating',
            'number' => $count,
            'echo'   => false,
        ));
        echo '<div class="vendor-rating">' . $star_rating_html . '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="vendor-rating">No ratings found yet!</div>';
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_vendor_rating', 60);
```

I am putting the code in fonction.php btw as I don't want to break anything. Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a CSS problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.